# Webpack: Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm getting

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 
HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin"
                                                          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Dependencies in **package.json**

**webpack** : `^3.10.0`

**@babel/core** : `^7.0.0-beta.38`

**@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import** : `^7.0.0-beta.38`

**@babel/plugin-transform-runtime** : `^7.0.0-beta.38`

**@babel/preset-env**: `^7.0.0-beta.38`

**babel-loader** : `^8.0.0-beta.0`

My configuration in **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

My **webpack.config.babel.js** configuration

```
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin"

export default {
  // Our index file
  entry:  "./src/app/app.js",
  output: {
    path:     `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: "index_bundle.js",
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test:    /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        include: `${__dirname}/app`,
        use:     {
          loader:  "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()],
}
```

When I `require` the `"html-webpack-plugin"`, and exporting the object with  `"module.exports"` it works fine but I'm trying to write this in ES6.

I would appreciate if someone could guide/ give me hints on how to achieve this.

Many thanks

Comment: Sounds like your webpack.config.babel.js is not being interpreted correctly from the babel compiler, if it is being interpreted. Which node version are you using? (also, which webpack version are you using?). Are you transpling the webpack config or..?

Comment: Using the on-site [search for your title](/search?q=Webpack%3A+Unexpected+token+import) returns a **lot** of results (more on searching [here](/help/searching), though in this case nothing advanced is required). What, **specifically**, from those questions' answers have you tried/checked/etc. before posting your question?

Comment: @briosheje My node is currently running version 8.9.0. I don't know, I'll do some reading and get back to you.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime`.

I've added `@babel/register` and everything works now.

[Link to SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235563/4608951)

Comment: Thank you, I have updated from webpack 2.x to 4.x, and import stopped working. This solved it and I can use import again in webpack's config file (webpack 4, babel 7).